# Word/phrase for straight-lined

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I don't even know how to describe my question, but it's like going in straight line vs not going in straight line, like:

[image]

what's the proper word/phrase to express the idea that

> I've __________ the convoluted process.

It's not *"simplify"*, it more about going in straight line now vs not going in straight line before, taking unnecessary steps and doing unnecessary things.

Is the *"straight-lined"* the proper phrase? I asked because at least *straightlining* has a total different meaning, and is more a negative word than a positive one, and I don't know how closely related the two are.

Comment: I'd stay it's still convoluted because you've put after before before!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## streamline

From Merriam-Webster:

> **streamline** *verb*
> **3 b :** to make simpler or more efficient
> *a system that streamlines the process*

This is a standard and very common verb in the business world that means *almost* exactly what you're asking. The only difference is that your arrow is straight, which suggests the process is as easy and efficient as possible. To *streamline*, on the other hand, only means to make it better, not perfect.

Answer (score 8):

*Straightened out* is a possibity, depending on context and precise meaning.

Comment: Native British English speaker here, I would say "straightened out" is more for where something is *wrong* with the process, that is it's "wonky" in some way and needs correcting.

Comment: @Muzer judging by the OP's image, the old process looked definitely wonky. 

Comment: Please don't take the line drawing too literally. As I don't even know how to describe my question so I illustrated it with an image. The situation might not be wrong, just doing unnecessary things.

Answer (score 2):

"Simplify" is still probably the best word, "simple" means fewer steps.

If there are fewer steps then you could say "shortened" the process.

Or rephrase

> I've made the process less convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your illustration, I think '[*disentangle*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disentangle)' comes closest:

> to free or become free from entanglement; untangle; extricate (often followed by from)

> "*I've disentangled the convoluted process.*"

Comment: I think that you're taking the line a bit too literally. As in, it's supposed to represent a process, it's not about the line itself.

Comment: @paddotk I get that, but the OP illustrated their situation that way, so this seems a very apt word choice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word ***linearize*** to very literally describe turning something into a straight line. A process that has been linearized would imply that it has a specified start and end point with step-by-step directions of how to implement the process. It connotes that the process does not involve a branching tree of decisions, but that one must move from step to step in a linear fashion.

Answer (score 1):

### Optimize

*verb:*

make the best or most effective use of (a situation, opportunity, or resource).

> I've **optimized** the convoluted process.

Comment: Hmm, _"optimized"_ to me implies that it is making something already good better, and doesn't convey the idea that it was _"taking unnecessary steps and doing unnecessary things"_ before.

Comment: @xpt Speaking as an engineer, I would say that anything removed in the process of optimization is by definition unnecessary.